# Creating AWS RDS instance using Chef cookbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, amazon-rds, chef-recipe

Forgive me if my question is too vague. I am new to both AWS and Chef automation tool. I am trying to create an RDS instance on AWS using Chef automation. I want the details of the RDS instance to be in the cookbook and I do not want to go through the AWS console. I did some research and found a community cookbook that does this:

https://github.com/gosuri/aws-rds-cookbook/blob/master/README.md

In my experience with Chef, I always had a node that I did sudo to, and it made sure that the node was following the policies listed in the cookbook.

I am confused here as I do not even have a node in the first place. I am trying to create one using cookbook. Is this possible? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chef is an agent-based system, so you need a node of some kind. With tools like [chef-provisioning](https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning) (you would want to use the AWS driver in this case) you sometimes use your workstation and run chef-client from there, or make a dedicated "provisioning node" which basically just sits there and does nothing but run provisioning recipes.